# Sorting text in recyclerview with custom layout

Tags: android, sorting, android-recyclerview

I want to sort my RecylerView in Alphabetical order. Im using a custom layout with an Image and a texbox. I want to sort my list in alphabetical order according to the text in my textbox.

My images are stored in drawable folder and are added to the recyclerview with their reference through an array.

```
int[] icons ={R.drawable.john,
            R.drawable.andrew,}
string[]title={"john","andrew"}
```

how do i sort the text so that each row is sorted alphabetically.

I was able to sort the title with

```
List<String> sortedName = Arrays.asList(title);
        Collections.sort(sortedName);
        title =(String[])sortedName.toArray()
```

however this only sorted the title and the images did not get sorted according to text.
Can someone help me to sort each row
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create an object containing both icon and title, like for instance

```
public class Entry implements Comparable<Entry>{
  private String title;
  private int icon;

  public Entry(String title, int icon){
   this.title = title;
   this.icon = icon;
  }

  public int compareTo(Entry new_entry) {
     return title.compareTo(new_entry.getTitle());
  }
  public String getTitle(){
    return this.title;
  }
  public int getIcon(){
    return this.icon;
  }
}
```

In this way, you can create an array of Entry objects and still using Collections.sort to sort entries.

You should slightly modify the adapter for the recyclerview and the job is done

Comment: Hi im new to recyclerview so you would have to break it down for me. Where do i add this class? Do i add it to my adapter?

Comment: you should use the class in same place where you create icons and title variable